# "Line by line" debug with custom Makefile

Tags: xcode, debugging, makefile

I am working with XCode and a C project developed in Linux. The thing is that it has some custom Makefiles so I had to create a new target specifying the external build system, and when I run the project it just outputs the bin file, no matter if there are any breakpoints. I would like the program to run within XCode so that I can debug it properly (line by line).

The "main" Makefile is:

```
all:
    $(MAKE) -C src
    mkdir -p bin
    mv src/program bin/program

debug:
    $(MAKE) -C src debug
    mkdir -p bin
    mv src/program bin/program

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C src clean
    rm -f bin/program
```

And in the src folder this is the Makefile:

```
SRC=[whatever]

OBJ=$(SRC:.c=.o)

CC=gcc
RM=rm -f

CFLAGS=[whatever]
LDFLAGS=[whatever]

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

all : program

program : $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) -o program $(LDFLAGS)

debug : CFLAGS += -DDEBUG -ggdb
debug : program

clean :
    $(RM) *.o program
```

(The [whatever]'s were added by me). So the question is: what should I do (modify the Makefiles,...) so that I can debug the program with breakpoints and line by line from XCode?

Comment: @IKavanagh The question is how to modify the Makefiles so that I can debug line by line from XCode (e.g., if I put a breakpoint the program stops there and I can go line by line).

Comment: What does XCode need about the build to make that work?

Comment: @EtanReisner I can't see where you are going, it's probably the first time I use a "customized" target with a Makefile, so I'm new to all this.

Comment: Are you trying to debug the make/build process or the built binary? If you are trying to debug the make/build process then I'm not at all sure what you actually want to do there (or how xcode can help). If you want to debug the binary then the question is just what does xcode need to be done to the binary/during the build so that it knows it can debug the binary.